# What's the meaning of this binary sequence arriving at my http server?

Tags: httpd, sniffing

I'm running a http [server](https://github.com/gchiu/rebol-httpd/blob/master/httpd.reb) written in Rebol and sometimes I see that the server is woken by data like this arriving at port 80

```
0300002F2AE00000000000436F6F6B69653A206D737473686173683D41646D696E697374720D0A0100080003000000
```

In the logs I see that over two days I've seen this happen three times.  Is this some type of attack?

The server is a F1 micro instance running on Google's compute cloud.

Comment: Most of the packet is ASCII: `Cookie: mstshash=Administr`. It is just some RDP worm.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks.  can you add that as an answer?

Comment: It's more of a hint, rather than an answer. Someone can certainly tell you what kind of virus/worm is it.

Comment: https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Random+Port+Scan+for+Open+RDP+Backdoor/24422/ discusses this as well